# URL of open(...) relative or absolute

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I don't quite understand the functioning of the `url` parameter of XMLHttpRequest `open(method, url, async)`. Let's say I have a web server like that:

[image]

`page.html` sends an asynchronous request to `controller.php`. As we can only send requests to our own web server, I assume that we don't have to rewrite the website's name in the URL.

**Example:** instead of `open('GET', 'http://www.mywebsite/controller.php', true)` we can simply write `open('GET', 'controller.php', true)`).

I don't get if this URL is relative to `page.html` or absolute from the root of the server.

---

**TL;DR:** Do I have to write `open('GET', 'controller.php?param=1', true)` or `open('GET', 'folder/controller.php?param=1', true)`?

Comment: i mean... one will work and one won't, should have been quite easy to figure out.

Comment: "As we can only send requests to our own web server" — [That isn't true](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: @KevinB I have tested both, I wanted to know if the error of my website comes from here.

Comment: Given your example (absolute url), `folder` **is** the root of your webserver.

Comment: @JacopoStanchi — What error?

Comment: @Quentin I'm using AJAX to send the data given by the user in input fields to do a research in the database with controller.php and the controller prints the results in a div, but it doesn't work, so I wondered if the URL was valid.

Comment: @JacopoStanchi — You need to provide a real [mcve] (and learn to use the debugging tools in your browser, the Network tab of the Developer Tools would show you the HTTP request and response you got).

Comment: I don't talk about my website specifically in this post, it is rather a broad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's relative to the folder of the page. All URLs in HTML and JavaScript are processed relative to the page (more precisely, the *base URL* of the page, which can be changed with a `<base>` tag).

So you should use:

```
open('GET', 'controller.php?param=1', true);
```

since the controller is in the same folder as the page calling it.

Comment: So I have to write `open('GET', 'controller.php?param=1', true)`? If so, can I also write `open('GET', 'http://www.mywebsite/folder/controller.php?param=1', true)`?

Comment: Of course you can. The rule only applies to relative URLs, absolute URLs are not affected.

Comment: Usually you use relative URLs so you can easily move everything to a different server or folder without having to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

As with all URLs in JavaScript, relative URLs are relative to the URL of the page the JavaScript code is running inside.